# ABC model selection from posterior samples

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, posterior, bayes-factors, approximate-bayesian-computation

I would like to know if there is a general scheme to do model selection based on the posterior samples from a set of ABC (Approximate Bayesian Computation) runs for a given set of models.

Particularly I was confused by [this question and answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/387769/abc-compute-bayes-factor-from-posteriors) which indicates that counting the accepted samples from resimulations from the *posterior parameters* provides an estimate for the model evidences (or Bayes factors). This seems in contradiction with this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bayesian-analysis/volume-6/issue-1/Likelihood-free-estimation-of-model-evidence/10.1214/11-BA602.full), where the fraction of accepted samples as a value for the evidence seems only true when sampling from the *prior*, *not the posterior*.

The same paper mentions slightly adapted schemes when the proposal distribution is not the prior, but they don't seem to apply for me as I'm not using ABC-SMC or ABC-MCMC.

So is there still a general way to get model evidences from ABC posteriors?

Besides I'm aware of the chat [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26980/abc-model-selection) citing this [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24774605); I will certainly try to find out whether my summary statistics are sufficient for model selection (once there is a way to do it from posterior samples in principle).

Any help really appreciated!

---

EDIT: After studying this a bit further, I may have found a solution based on the above paper ([Didelot et al., 2011](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bayesian-analysis/volume-6/issue-1/Likelihood-free-estimation-of-model-evidence/10.1214/11-BA602.full)), which I scetch below. Still, as I'm far from being an expert on this topic, it would be awesome if people would comment on this!

This solution also requires re-simulations, but can be done "closer" to the posterior samples than from an uninformed prior.

Let $D$ be the data, and $\theta$ the parameter vector of a given model $M$ that can simulate data $D_{\theta}$ with these parameters.

Then we have the parameter prior $p(\theta | M)$ of model $M$ and the desired model evidence given by $p(D|M)$.

Further $\pi_{\epsilon}(D_{\theta}|D)$ is (in a simple case) the indicator function ($1$ if distance $d(D,D_{\theta})<\epsilon$ else $0$).

From an ABC run, we obtained $N$ posterior samples $\theta_1$, ..., $\theta_N$. Following "Algorithm 5" of that paper we have

For $i=1,...,N$
(1) Generate $\theta_i^{*} \sim Q(\theta|\theta_i)$
(2) Simulate $D_{\theta_{i}^{*}}$ using $\theta_i^{*}$
(3) Compute $w_i = \frac{p(\theta_i^{*}|M) \pi_{\epsilon}(D_{\theta_{i}^{*}}|D)}{q(\theta_i^{*})}$,

where $q(\theta_i^{*}) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N Q(\theta_i^{*}|\theta_j)$. Then $p(D|M) \approx {\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w_i}$.

Above, $Q(\theta|\theta_i)$ is a distribution that functions as transition (or mutation or perturbation) kernel. I think the idea is to add "some noise" to the actual posterior samples $\theta_i$ to come up with proposals $\theta_i^{*}$ in each iteration. $q(\theta_i^{*})$ then computes the local volume, to be weighted with the prior to get above weights $w_i$.

If one chooses $Q$ to be the prior itself, above weights simplify to the more standard prior- and rejection-based ABC evidence calculation (i.e. $w_i = \pi_{\epsilon}(D_{\theta_{i}^{*}}|D)$). However, using some $Q$ closer to the posterior will result in more efficient acceptance rates.

From that paper I understand that $Q(\theta | \theta_i)$ should be heavy-tailed. So for practical purposes I'm thinking of a non-standardised t-distribution with mean $\theta_i$ and standard deviation that is on a scale of the posterior samples.

Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: I do not see where my answer is confusing but standard ABC model choice means picking model index and parameter value from the prior, and then comparing ensuing pseudo-data with actual data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting! I think my confusion came from the question, where OP asked about resimulations from the _posterior_, not the prior. If I understand correctly now, it has to be from the prior for the standard rejection based model choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate, free, solution is to run an ABC version of [harmonic mean evidence approximation](https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2008/08/17/the-harmonic-mean-of-the-likelihood-worst-monte-carlo-method-ever/) à la Newton & Raftery (1994). Since
$$\mathcal Z=1\Big/\int \dfrac{\pi(\theta|D)}{p(D|\theta)}\,\text d\theta$$
the evidence can formally be approximated by
$$\hat{\mathcal Z} =1\Big/\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{p(D|\theta_i)}\qquad\theta_i\sim\pi(\theta|D)$$
and its ABC version is
$$\hat{\mathcal Z} =1\Big/\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{K_\epsilon(d(D,D^\star(\theta_i)))}\qquad\theta_i\sim\pi^\epsilon(\theta|D)$$
where $K_\epsilon(\cdot)$ is the kernel used for the ABC acceptance step and $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the distance used to measure the discrepancy between samples.

An attempt at using this approach on a toy model showed a moderazte discrepancy with the actual evidence. Using the model
$$\theta\sim\mathcal N(0,10)\qquad x|\theta\sim\mathcal N(\theta,1)$$
with the observation $x^\text{o}=3$, the actual evidence is 8 $10^{-2}$ while the approximation returns a lower 2.5 $10^{-2}$ when the scale in the Cauchy kernel is chosen to produce a good fit of the ABC posterior:

[image]

However, estimating directly the marginal density with the same Cauchy kernel is producing a much closer approximation, namely 7.8 $10^{-2}$. Here is the R code I used in this experiment:

```
o=3;e=rnorm(1e6,sd=sqrt(10));k=1+100*(o+rnorm(1e6)-e)^2
print(c(1/mean(k[runif(1e6)*k<1]),mean(10/k/pi),dnorm(o,sd=sqrt(11))))
```

Comment: Thank you! I wondered why I could not find an approximation based on the posterior samples per se, so there it is. However, after reading the linked blog post, its usage cannot really be recommended... This [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5123) introduces a modification: sampling from a density of lighter tails than the posterior based on a HPD region. Can this be used?

Comment: Radford Neal made it quite clear why harmonic means are not advisable in most situations. However, this is somewhat different in that the ABC kernel $K_\epsilon$ can be selected towards its inverse having light enough tails.

Comment: Thank you so much for adding the example!! It is super helpful and I'm able to reconstruct it. One question: could it be that the HME just misses the correct kernel normalisation? Basically change it to `1/mean(k[runif(1e6)*k<1.0]*pi/10)`, as you have also done it in the direct MC estimation. If I do this I get much closer values.

Comment: Good point. I was stuck in thinking of 1/k as an acceptance probability in ABC, but there is no need for the harmonic estimate to keep this constraint.

Comment: super, then I will certainly try the HME on my problems, thank you altogether!